# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null error

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm very new to MVC and I'm trying to create an upload file input type of form that allows the user to upload a file, it reads the contents and displays them in a table. but I keep getting this error. 
The line that gives me this error is the if Model.Count line in my view and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Here's my code:

Controller:

```
      public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new List<CategoryModel>());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
    {
        List<CategoryModel> categories = new List<CategoryModel>();
        string filePath = string.Empty;
        if (postedFile != null)
        {
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }

            filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
            postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

            //Read the contents of CSV file.
            string csvData = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);


            //Execute a loop over the rows.
            foreach (string row in csvData.Split('\n'))
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row))
                {
                    categories.Add(new CategoryModel
                    {
                        CategoryID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Split(',')[0]),
                        Name = row.Split(',')[1],
                        Item = row.Split(',')[2]
                    });
                }
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
}
```

}

And Model:

```
{
public class CategoryModel
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }   
    public string Item { get; set; }
}
```

And View:

```
 @{
    ViewBag.Title = "View";
}

<h2>View</h2>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
        <span>Select File:</span>
        <input type="file" name="postedFile" />
        <hr />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    }
    @if (Model.Count() > 0)
    {
        <hr />
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <th>CategoryID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Item</th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (CategoryModel category in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@category.CategoryID</td>
                    <td>@category.Name</td>
                    <td>@category.Item</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Paste the error message please

Comment: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: source'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this in your controller action:

```
return View();
```

You are not passing a model to the view, so `Model` in the view is `null`.  When you try to call extension methods (like `.Count()`) on a `null` reference, that's the error you get.  (Since it's technically not a `NullReferenceException`, but rather the extension method checking if the first argument is `null` and throwing an exception.)

You'll need to either check for `null` in your view, or always pass an instance of the model.  Like you do in your first controller action:

```
return View(new List<CategoryModel>());
```

---

As an aside, after a successful POST action it's generally customary to redirect the user instead of return the view.  That way the browser sends a new HTTP GET request for the redirect so if the user reloads the page it doesn't re-POST the form, but just reloads the GET.

So instead of this:

```
return View();
```

You might do this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```